# Mapbox App Submission Error

Tags: ios, app-store, mapbox, appstore-approval

I have built the application using the Mapbox framework. The app run on device and pass the App submission validation process.

However, when I try to submit the App on App Store, I a getting error as

***ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for AppName.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."***

I had tried different solutions but no luck yet.

e.g. http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

However on [Mapbox cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK) and some other frameworks, they mention that

***The last step, courtesy of Realm, is required for working around an iOS [App Store bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216) when archiving universal binaries***

Can anyone please let me know how to solve this error or how to use courtesy of Realm to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/) dynamic framework installation instructions:

> In the Build Phases tab of the project editor, click the + button at the top and select “New Run Script Phase”. Enter the following code into the script text field:

```
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Mapbox.framework/strip-frameworks.sh”
```

This works around an [App Store bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216) wherein the simulator slices aren’t stripped from the framework.

Comment: Thanks @friedbunny for your reply. I have added that script at the time of configuring the Mapbox framework. But when I was sharing the build for testing, I am getting error for Archiving. So I removed that script. 
Does this script only need to add at the App submission time? Will it get error if we try to Archive using Development Provision Profile?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK

In the Build Phases tab, click the + button at the top and select “New Run Script Phase”. Enter the following code into the script text field:

bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Mapbox.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"

And archive and upload it to iTune.